# EF Core Oracle table does not exist error

Tags: oracle, ef-core-3.1

I am using Dot Net Core 3.1 , EF Core and Oracle.EntityframeworkCore

Steps I followed :

1. Created a table named "USER" in Oracle using Toad , with following DDL statement

```
CREATE TABLE POLICYAPP.USER {
ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
USERNAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
PASSWORDHASH VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
};
```

where the schema name is "POLICYAPP"

2. Verified that the table "USER" is present in the schema "POLICYAPP"
3. Created Dot net Core WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2019
4. Created "Models" folder and created class "User.cs" with below definition

```
[Table("USER", Schema = "POLICYAPP")]
public class User 
{
  [key]
  [column("ID")]
  public int id {get; set;}

  [column("USERNAME")]
  public string username {get; set;}

  [column("PASSWORDHASH")]
  public string passwordhash {get; set;)

  

}
```

5. Create AppDbContext class that contains following

public DbSet Users {get; set;}

6. Created "Repositories" folder and created interface "IAuthRepository" with method findByUsername
   Also, created class "AuthRepository" that implements the interface "IAuthRepository" using LINQ query
7. Modified Startup.cs to include following in ConfigureServices method

```
var connstring = Configuration.GetConnectionString("poldb");
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext> {
  options => options.useOracle(connstring)
};

services.AddScoped<IAuthRepoistory, AuthRepository>;
```

8. The file appsettings.json has proper connection string.
9. Created "Controllers" folder and created class "AuthController" in the folder
   The controller invokes the repository find method to search by username

The issue is :
When I run the app and enter url http:\localhost:10220\api\Authn\John, it fails with error
"OracleException: ora-00942 table or view does not exist"

Added below code in AppDbContext.cs , still get the same error

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("POLICYAPP");
}
```

Comment: Does the Oracle user in your code have privileges granted to it?

Comment: Yes, the Oracle user in the connection string (in appsetting.json) is attached to a role. This role has has the required privileges,

Comment: My understanding was incorrect. The issue was the privilege for the new table was not done. Thanks so much for your quick response, really appreciate it